# Dropdown html displaying divs

Tags: html

I am wanting to create a **JavaScript drop down** for my website and I want it to display divs underneath.

```
<select name="Portfolio">    
<option id="1">Option 1</option>
<option id="2">Option 2</option>
<option id="3">Option 3</option>
<option id="4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<div id="1"><img src="URL" alt="Blah Blah Blah"/></div>
<div id="2"><img src="URL" alt="Blah Blah Blah"/></div>
```

What JavaScript code do i need for this to work? Any help will be greatly appreciated! I have looked at so many others but can't seem to get anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="Portfolio" id="portfolio">
<option>None</option>      
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option alue="4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<div id="1" style="display:none;"><img src="URL" alt="Blah Blah Blah"/></div>
<div id="2" style="display:none;"><img src="URL" alt="Blah Blah Blah"/></div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        $('div').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

run this in jsfiddle

Comment: I put this into jsfiddle and i can't get it to work > [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Xe4tt/)

Answer (score 0):

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/visnupriya/AvxPe/) link  demo

```
<select name="Portfolio">
<option>None</option>      
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<div id="1" style="display:none;"><img src="img1" alt="Blah Blah Blah"/></div>

<div id="2" style="display:none;"><img src="img2" alt="Blah Blah Blah"/></div>

var old_id
$(function(){
  $("select").change(function(){
       $('div').css('display','none');
       $('#'+$(this).val()).css('display','block');
  });
});
```

Comment: i tried using this but I cant seem to get it working > [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wumsf/)  and what do the '$' mean? Is there a way to code it without those?

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/ Nowdays people use jquery. It is advance one depend on javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're using `id` attributes in `<option>` i'd suggest using `value` instead; so your markup would be somewhat like this:

```
<select name="Portfolio">    
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

then, if you're not using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) a simple javascript approach to your problem would be like:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

In case you've have a problem with multiple images showing up on subsequent drop-down changes, hide all the divs every time the `onchange()` is triggered

[see this working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LesZK/)